# Photon energy-momentum relation inside a material

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

I understand that the speed of light in a medium like glass, $c_n$, is reduced by the refractive index $n$ so that we have:
$$c_n=\frac{c}{n},$$
where $c$ is the speed of light in the vacuum.

Is it true that in the medium
$$E_n = |\vec{p_n}|\ c_n,$$
where $E_n$ is the energy of a photon in the medium and $\vec{p_n}$ is its momentum?

Comment: i.e. the problem is unsolved, and is still argued over. The momentum changes, and then the energy can be derived using conservation laws.